# How to simplify symbolic matrix multiplication results?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic

I've defined three symbolic abstract matrices X, M and S as shown below.

```
In[1]:= $Assumptions = { 
Element[X, Matrices[{k, 1}]],
Element[M, Matrices[{k, 1}]],
Element[S, Matrices[{k, k}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]]
};

In[7]:= prodA = TensorTranspose[X].S.M;
        prodB = TensorTranspose[M].S.X;

In[12]:= TensorReduce[prodA + prodB]
Out[12]= TensorTranspose[M, {2, 1}].S.X + TensorTranspose[X, {2, 1}].S.M
```

Since the S is a square and symmetric matrix, the production results prodA and prodB should be equal. How can I let the output reflect that? I need the output show something like 2TensorTranspose[X].S.M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `Matrices[{k, 1}]` to `Vectors[k]`

```
$Assumptions = {Element[X, Vectors[k]], Element[M, Vectors[k]], 
   Element[S, Matrices[{k, k}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]]};

prodA = X.S.M; (* vector not needed to be transposed *)
prodB = M.S.X;

TensorReduce[prodA + prodB]
```

> ```
> 2 M.S.X
> ```

`TensorReduce` can't simplify `Matrices[{k, 1}]` because your relation is not true for general dimensions:

```
u = RandomReal[1.0, {10, 2}];
v = RandomReal[1.0, {10, 2}];
m = (# + Transpose[#]) &@RandomReal[1.0, {10, 10}];

Transpose[u].m.v // MatrixForm
Transpose[v].m.u // MatrixForm
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exactly, using Vector declaration solves the problem. You're absolutely right! Thank you!